# How to inherit a class from an assembly without forcing users to reference two assemblies

Tags: .net, inheritance, assemblies

I have two classes A and B in two different .NET assemblies: AssemblyA and AssemblyB.

I want class B to inherit class A but I want that however uses class B to only need to reference AssemblyB (and not both AssemblyA and AssemblyB).

Due to the project constraints I need to keep the two assemblies separate so I cannot use merge tool to merge the two assemblies.

Note that actual inheritance of classes is not a must - I want to be able to have logic from A run in AssemblyB as part of class B with as little as possible rewriting of functionality.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Think of it in this way - suppose youI type in the following:

```
public class B : A
{
      public void Foo()
      {
            this.// Cursor is here
      }
}
```

How do you expect Intellisense to know what's available if it doesn't know what's in class A? How would the compiler be able to validate method calls etc?

You *have* to know about the parent classes all the way up the inheritance chain. This means referencing both projects. If you don't want to do this, don't use inheritance - make B compose A instead of deriving from it. Users will still need the binary for A available at execution time, but I don't *think* they'll need to add a reference in Visual Studio. (On the other hand, if they're going to debug the code, they'll probably want to anyway to make sure the binary is in the right place...)